# c# comparing current windows user to AD group

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to grab the current windows user and see if that user is part of a certain group in Active Directory. The username information finds "Harper\TSmith" which seems fine but when I get to the

```
UserPrincipal uPrincipal = Psearch.FindOne() as UserPrincipal
```

Line UPrincipal is null. Can not figure out why. I also have at the bottom a validator class that as a bool method to see if they are part of that particular group.

```
PrincipalContext principalCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            UserPrincipal findUser = new UserPrincipal(principalCtx);
            //findUser.Name = Environment.UserName;
            findUser.Name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            PrincipalSearcher pSearch = new PrincipalSearcher();
            pSearch.QueryFilter = findUser;
            UserPrincipal uPrincipal = pSearch.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;

            Validator validate = new Validator();
            //validate.IsUserInGroup("VisualOne", uPrincipal);

            if (validate.IsUserInGroup("MyGroup", uPrincipal))
            {
                var MemberShipForm = new Membership();
                MemberShipForm.Show();
            }



public bool IsUserInGroup(string groupName, UserPrincipal user)
    {
        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Harper");
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "MyGroup");

        if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Would probably be good policy to post the code related to pSearch.FindOne() as it dictates what uPrincipal  is equal to.

Comment: I have no code for pSearch.FindOne() I thought that FindOne was a method of PrincipalSearcher class and I could call it by setting pSearch.QueryFilter = findUser?

Comment: I see that now, silly mistake. Let me look more into the methods and I'll let you know if I see anything.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out doing too much just had to change UserPrincipal uPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PrincipalContext principalCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal uPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;

 if (validate.IsUserInGroup("MyGroup", uPrincipal))
            {
                var MemberShipForm = new Membership();
                MemberShipForm.Show();
            }
```